# How do I start a function with serial input?

Tags: serial

I want to create a LED Sunrise/Sundown alarm clock. Therefore, I will use a Raspberry Pi that is sending commands over serial to a Teensy 3.1. Like:

- "30 Minute Sunrise starting with Color(255,140,0)"
- "20 Minute Sundown with Color(255,140,0)"
- "start something else with these 3 parameter.

But I don't even get the basic serial part working. E.g. I tried this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  strip.begin();
  strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    if (Serial.read() == 'A'){
      int inte1 = Serial.parseInt();
      int inte2 = Serial.parseInt();
      int inte3 = Serial.parseInt();
      int inte4 = Serial.parseInt();
      int inte5 = Serial.parseInt();
      if (Serial.read() == '\n') {
        Serial.print(inte1);
        Serial.print(inte2);
        Serial.print(inte3);
        Serial.print(inte4);
        Serial.println(inte5);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I planned to do a `case` switch afterwards. `Inte1` should define sunrise/sundown, `Inte2` the minutes, 'Inte3-5' the rgb color.

However, when I enter "A 1 100 100 100" it is not printing anything at all.

What is the best way do get this working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggested reading: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino

Comment: Thank you, that was a nice read. The examples compiles fine and I get what this is about, but still not working. Does not print a single line on the serial monitor!

Comment: Baud in Teensy and serial monitor is the same!

Comment: Have you managed to get even simple "echo what you send" serial communication working?

Comment: Yes. Right now: 'char exstr = Serial.read(); Serial.print(exstr)' is working. I don't know why the example does not!

Comment: Probably because you're not waiting for the `\n` and expecting it to already be in the serial buffer when it hasn't actually arrived yet. Don't expect it to be there immediately you have parsed the last int.

Comment: I think Majenko is right. Suggested alternative method: [How to process incoming serial data without blocking](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial)

Comment: Yes that `\n` was missing. Without it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as Majenko and Nick Gammon have suggested. The `\n` had not arrived in the serial buffer. That way the if clause was not fulfilled and nothing was printed. This code has worked for me now:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
 if (Serial.read() == 'A'){
  char inte1 = Serial.read();
  int inte2 = Serial.parseInt();
  int inte3 = Serial.parseInt();
  int inte4 = Serial.parseInt();
  int inte5 = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.print(inte1);
  Serial.print(inte2);
  Serial.print(inte3);
  Serial.print(inte4);
  Serial.println(inte5);
 }
}
```

Although i read quite a bit now, serial input is still a mystery to me.